# Domain issues calling routes in AWS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, express

I found some code to be able to call nodemailer to send email from a form. On the form itself I am calling my route with a hard coded route.

```
$.get("http://ec2-54-204-182-151.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/send",passData,function(data){
            if(data=="sent")
            {
                $("#message").empty().html("Email has been sent at "+$scope.to+" . Please check inbox!");
            }
        });
```

On localhost it works, and doesn't complain. When I call the same code with my aws domain and port number, I get the following:

> XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location:
>   http://ec2-54-204-182-151.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/send?name=todd&email=tcoulson%40gmail.com&subject=hello&message=now%20we%20have%20it&to=tcoulson%40gmail.com
>   Line Number 1, Column 1:

Is there a way I can rewrite the call so it does not rely on a hard coded path. I started writing $http directive to post in angularjs, but I was having trouble getting the data to be read in. Here is that code:

```
$http({
            url: '/send',
            method: "POST",
            data: passData,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
```

And finally here is the route I am trying to call.

```
app.post('/send',function(req,res){
        var mailOptions={
            to : 'buckscountytourofhonor@gmail.com',
            from: req.query.email,
            subject : req.query.subject,
            text : req.query.name +": "+req.query.message
        }
        console.log(mailOptions);
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
            if(error){
                console.log(error);
                res.end("error");
            }else{
                console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
                res.end("sent");
            }
        });
```

I assume at the moment it is not req.query to get data back from the $http - that did work for $.get. Let me know if I am on the right track with the $http call and where I may be able to write my code cleaner to remove the hard coded url.

EDIT: So I was able to change my code to use body-parser with express to get info from angular, to my express route and successfully send an email on localhost. But when I put it up on AWS, it fails with: The connection used to fetch this resource was not secure.

Comment: If i open url in browser it get only this `error` so may be somthing wrong with script or AWS security settings? Try to open  http://ec2-54-204-182-151.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/send?name=todd&email=tcoulson%40gmail.com&subject=hello&message=now%20we%20have%20it&to=tcoulson%40gmail.com in browser and paste result

Comment: Yeah that error is a result of res.end("error"); this call. I think I am calling the wrong properties to it. I will check them tonight.